# Random sampling with replacement, increasing groupsize, sum and append in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe which i'd like to repeatedly sample, with replacement. Everytime I sample the df, I would like to increase the size of the sample (n) by one, up to N.

For example:

| id | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 10 |
| b | 10 | 30 |
| c | 6 | 8 |
| d | 9 | 12 |

Would result in something like

| id's | sum_of_value_1 | sum_of_value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | 10 | 30 |
| a, c | 11 (5+6) | 18 (10+8) |
| b,a,d | 24 (10+5+9) | 52 (30+10+12) |

I can do this with a for loop but can't figure how how to add the summation and the append into the query:

```
for n in range(200):
    print(df_groups.sample(n))
```

Comment: The logic is unclear to me, can you break down an example?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I was confused by the fact that the last two rows both had 2 items

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pandas.Dataframe.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) for summation of all columns and then use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatinate the new single row dataframe at the end of a new dataframe that you can use as an accumulator  of samples.

maybe something like this

```py
acc = df_groups.sample(1).aggregate('sum')
for n in range(2, df_groups.shape[0]):
    pd.concat([acc, df_groups.sample(n).aggregate('sum')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (pd.concat({n: df.sample(n)
                  for n in range(1, len(df))})
         .groupby(level=0)
         .agg({'id': ','.join,
               'value_1': 'sum',
               'value_2': 'sum'
              })
       )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
      id  value_1  value_2
1      a        5       10
2    b,c       16       38
3  a,c,d       20       30
```